# Any workaround to Subversion HTTP download resume limitation?

Tags: proxy, svn, http

I recently encounter a problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/12365109/151453 . Since the Subversion repository files served by HTTP(svn 1.7) does not support download resume, is there any reverse proxy technique that can cache the svn files then serve to clients with resume support?

Comment: Are you just trying to serve the files, or do you need the full SVN WebDAV functionality in addition to allowing `Range` requests?  Can you explain your use case (why do you need `Range` requests)?

Comment: Currently, serving files via http is enough, in premise that those files are stored in my SVN repository.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're needing `Range` support for?  It seems like just having a post-commit hook export to your web root might work just fine.. but I'm not sure if that makes sense, depends how you're using it.

Comment: I need Range support so that user can resume a large file(e.g. 100MB) download on a poor network condition. post-commit hook may be a reasonable idea, however, I think it will not be able to cope with file fetching with peg revision in URL(get an older version of a file).

Answer (score 2):

Since svn 1.7.6, an `Expires:` header is sent in response to certain requests ([commit message](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-commits/201206.mbox/%3C20120614141313.9FDE0238896F@eris.apache.org%3E)) -- so yes, a reverse proxy like nginx will cache them.  I didn't test this and svn.apache.org is still running 1.7.5.

Also, it appears that range requests worked in early svn versions (older than 1.2) -- [svn-users post from 2005](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2005-11/0603.shtml); you could ask for advice on that list.

Comment: ``Expires`` header? My Windows SVN server happens to be 1.7.6(binary from CollabNet webset). When I try ``wget -c -d http://down.nlscan.com:82/Release/GMU/gmu-symbols.htm``, I do not see the ``Expires`` header. Can you  further explain it?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the commit message; that change is not present in any released version yet -- it was not merged to 1.7.x release branch.  Plus, it actually adds `Cache-Control:` header, not `Expires:`